# Deploying WCF Service Host App without WCF Service Host?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, service

I have a WCF service hosted by a simple WinForms app. In Visual Studio the service is started via the built in WCF Service Host & everything works fine. I now want to host the service in my host app but currently the service doesn't run.

Service App:

```
  ServiceHost host;
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        host = new ServiceHost(typeof(RegimesService));
        host.Open();
        lblStatus.Text = "Started...";
    }
```

If I close WCF Service Host in the sys tray & click my start button, the code runs but the service never starts?

Here's my Service Host App config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="metaBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
       <service name="diiRegimesService.RegimesService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="diiRegimesService.IRegimesService"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8081" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

& Finally my Service project App.config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="diiRegimesService.RegimesService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="diiRegimesService.IRegimesService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
               maxArrayLength="200000000"
               maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

When I run `netstat -a` from cmd line, the port `http://localhost:8080` isn't listening so it's like the service object never actually gets initialized. I'm sure it's a simple mistake in my configs somewhere, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Try to run host application as Administrator

Answer (score 1):

Port 8080 is a reserved port for SQL Server, Also your service App.config and Host App.config are having different ports in their base address

Comment: Tried on 8082 & various others, no luck. Just getting the 'Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.' screen in the browser.

Comment: try making base address in both App.config same, you can try it with localhost:80.

Comment: Yes, tried this, same result. If I try to restart the service at run time I get an exception of type 'Port already in use' so the app is obviously registering the address...

Comment: try the instructions given in this [URL]([link](http://keithelder.net/2008/01/17/exposing-a-wcf-service-) and make sure that you are not missing anything

Answer (score 0):

Ok, used the WCF configuration wizard from Solution Explorer & tied the `ServiceBehaviour` to the Service definition in the Host App's `App.Config` & hey presto, everything is wired up & working! Thanks for your help @Akshay Choudhary.